# Self Hosting Forward Proxy For VPN

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn

I am currently using OpenVPN to connect company network on Windows 10. However I want only certain applications to access it via VPN while other stay on my own network.

Right now I can solve that problem by connecting to VPN from my other computer then creating a forward proxy with using Squid. Is there any software solutions where I can host forward proxy using my own computer and use that instead of using another computer on same network?

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY supports bidirectional SSH port forwarding. Just open an SSH server on either computer, download PuTTY, and follow [these directions](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html).